# Grub doesn't find any partition, what can I do?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, grub

So I just recently installed Ubuntu Linux 10.04 on my desktop machine alongside Windows 7, it booted just fine the first few times but after I went into my Windows 7 recovery software provided by Packard Bell (I did this on accident BTW I exited it straight away and made no changes as far as I know) and re-booted I get this screen:

```
error: no such partition

grub rescue>_
```

PS: I have installed it on a USB stick using the ISO on the official Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i fixed it, just re-installed Ubuntu and it overwrote the old bootloader.